# Facebook Page Feed - Full Height

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe, plugins

Just like the title says. I want to insert a FB page feed that stretches to the end of the window. Is this possible? 800px is the highest it wants to go I think, when I set it on iframe. And I've searched everywhere for an answer, but no luck.

I've used [Facebook page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin), of course. And here's the outline of my code, using Bootstrap 4.

```css
.card {
  position: fixed;
  width: 340px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card p-0">
  <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMercedesAMG&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default height can be set through your app dashboard (on the Facebook Developers website). setting it to 'fluid' should allow you to resize it on the fly.

Then you should apply a 100% `height` to the `iframe` itself and set a `min-height` to your container.